# How to do JMeter ip spoofing on Mac?

Tags: macos, performance, jmeter

Just try to figure out how to do ip spoofing in JMeter on my mac. What is done is that I created file which contains ip addresses somewhere in my subnetwork. 
When I try to run thread JMeter shows me:

> java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address

Only my IP has ping. So, could you please advice me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an IP alias from Terminal application (it is under Applications -> Utilities) as

```
sudo ifconfig en0 alias 192.168.0.12 255.255.255.0
```

where:

- `en` - is Network Interface name
- `192.168.0.12` - is the IP alias

[image: MacOSX IP Alias]

Once you set up the alias, you can use new IP address in the "Source address" input

[image: JMeter Source Address]

And HTTP requests will use that IP address as source one:

[image: JMeter IP spoofing]

You can remove the IP alias when it is no longer required as

```
sudo ifconfig en0 -alias 192.168.0.12
```

See [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) guide for more detailed information on the domain.